# maximum http request in a page

Tags: http, browser, httpwebrequest, http-headers

How many http request does a browser can handle in a single html page.
Their is a popular saying that browser can handle only a certain http request from a single domain and so its better to create static domain(cdn). so that http request can be shared between the 2 domains.

q1)How many http request can a browser handle in a single html page or atleast the saturation point(say 1000 requests)?

q2)How many http request from a single domain name can a browser render(say 100 from the same domain name)?

also any suggestions for best practices!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory there is no limit. But as the number of requests required to construct a page grows, the time taken for the page to be rendered increases. The relationship is not linear at low counts. Typically latency has a far bigger effect than bandwidth on actual throughput and there are mechanisms in HTTP to minimise the effect of this - such as keepalives and parallel requests. As Jon Grant says, there are limits on the number of **concurrent** requests.

A full answer to this question would fill a book - [here's a good one](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596529307).

Answer (score 3):

[Section 8.1.4 of the HTTP/1.1 RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.1.4) says a "single-user client SHOULD NOT maintain more than 2 connections with any server or proxy."

However, the key word is "should"; most browsers use a different number. See [this blog](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/03/20/roundup-on-parallel-connections/) for a table of max connections per browser.

Comment: jon that was an excellent answer, although my question was very basic i did ask for how many http request a browser can handle, something like http://exp.com/img1.png,http://exp.com/jq.js,http://exp.com/img2.jpg ........ and so on , i think you can get my point